# Why do H1 tags not need a class or id in the css?

Tags: css

I was just looking at my CSS and the h1 tag is defined like this:

```
h1 { .... }
```

When everything else either has an id "#" or a "." class preceding it. What is the reason header tags don't need this? Have I infact made a mistake and they do need one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This means that *all occurences* of `h1` will share the same style. Similarly, you can have a style defined for any other element, e.g.:

```
p { font-family: Helvetica; }
```

That means all `p` tags will use the Helvetica font.

Note that it's also a best practice to have just one `h1` element in a page.

You can find a brief overview what different types of selectors mean [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

Answer (score 4):

It's said in [the doc](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#type-selectors):

> 5.4 Type selectors
>
> A type selector matches the name of a document language element type.
>   A type selector matches every instance of the element type in the
>   document tree.

So any valid element may be selected just by specifying its name. It also works in more complex selectors, by the way.

Answer (score 2):

Its not just header tags. All **elements** are "selected" simply by their name alone. '#' is used to "select" by id and "." is used to "select" by class.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is not that the "h1" tag does not need to have "class or id". It can have a class or id just like other tags. It is just up to you, and how you use it. As mentioned in other answers if you want to apply a specific style to all your h1, then you will have it without a class and your CSS would be: h1{...}

But if you want to use specific styles to each "h1" tag you have, then you can use a class attribute to identify each one "h1", see the following example:

Let's say you have two "h1" tags in your HTML code and you want to style each one with a different color, then you can do the following:

HTML:

```
<h1 class="first-header">Hello World1</h1>
<h1 class="second-header">Hello World2</h1>
```

CSS:

```
h1.first-header{color:red;}
h1.second-header{color:blue;}
```

This will display your first h1 in red color and the second in blue.